# Disable scaling of the WebView

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a problem where I have the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <OTHERVIEWS..../>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/WebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to be able to scale every child in the RelativeLayout - BUT without scaling the WebView. Is it at all possible to do this:

```
    findViewById(R.id.Parent).animate().scaleX(0.75f).scaleY(0.75f).setDuration(750).start();
```

And then override some method in the WebView to make it ignore its parent scaling - or some other way? Any ideas?

I know the easiest solution is just to scale on each specific child - but since I need this functionality in a lot of places it would be the best solution to do this generically in the webview.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish visually? Your WebView is declared in a RelativeLayout but you have not laid it out relative to any of the other Views inside.

Comment: I have simplified this alot - the whole application is built around that you can click on a button to scale the entire window (to gain room for extra text around the window). But the Webview has an issue where it looses some of it content when scaling its parent (error in 4.2.2)

Comment: You need to post some pictures of what you are talking about so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

you are accessing parent id like

```
findViewById(R.id.Parent).animate().scaleX(0.75f).scaleY(0.75f).setDuration(750).start();
```

All other View including WebView is inside it . When you animate the Parent View all child View will also animate..  Simply create another layout (Which you want to animate or i mean which area you want to animate )

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/AnimatingLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <OTHERVIEWS..../>

</RelativeLayout>// it is the end of AnimatingLayout

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/WebView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Now get the id of AnimatingLayout like

```
findViewById(R.id.AnimatingLayout).animate().scaleX(0.75f).scaleY(0.75f).setDuration(750).start();
```

// only those view will animate which were the child of AnimatingLayout (RelativeLayout).

Ask me if any other problem..